# HttpErrorResponse Error in posting data using angular formbuilder.group

Tags: angular, forms, http, post, request

i am trying to post data to api from the input field - but i am gettint this error - user is not allowed.

[HttpResponseError - username is not allowed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pz5P5.jpg)

if i try to comment out the code like this

**user.add.component.ts**

```
   this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],


 /*username: ['', Validators.required],
   email: ['', Validators.compose([
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$')
  ])], */

});
```

If i only leave just one input - name, then it gets posted and works fine.

**service.ts**

```
createUser(us:user):Observable<user[]>{
       return this.http.post<user[]>(this.apiUrl, us)
    }
```

**express.js api**

```
app.post('/api/users', (req, res) => {

const schema = {
    name: Joi.string().min(3).required(),
};
const { error } = validateUser(req.body);
if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
console.log('---------------', req.body.name);

const user = {
    id: users.length + 1,
    name: req.body.name,
    Username:req.body.username,
    Email:req.body.email

};

users.push(user);
res.send(user);
```

});

So i am not sure if there is something with angular formGroup missplacement
or my express.js api.

Comment: share code for `validateUser`

Comment: http://collabedit.com/nnfk6

Comment: the method `validateUser` is on the server side. `validateUser` returns an error, this is why I wanted to see what's inside it

Comment: Thank you Vadi, i looked in that method and found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was inside my express.js in validateUser method as Vaid mentioned.
 i didn't had included username and email in that method, thats why i was gettint an error

```
   function validateUser(user){
    const schema = {
    name: Joi.string().min(3).required(),
    username:Joi.string().min(3).max(30).required(),
    email: Joi.string().email({ minDomainAtoms: 2 })
     };
    return result = Joi.validate(user, schema);
      }
```